# What parameter of function

Tags: java

```
class Scroll {
    static boolean up;
    static boolean down;
    public static void scroll(boolean direction) {
        if (/* ... */) {
            System.out.println("UP");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("DOWN");
    }
}

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scroll.scroll(Scroll.up);
    }
}
```

**How can I check which field has function been called with - with `Scroll.up` or `Scroll.down`?** I know that in above code I could get same effect in other way, but it's simplified code with essence of my problem.

Comment: I'm very beginner and I didn't realised that I'll have to use enum. Thanks, that's what I was looking for :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the only choices are up or down, you can rename `direction` as `up` and then:

```
if (up) {
    // Up
}
else {
    // Down
}
```

If there are more directions (left and right, for instance), or even if not really, this is where `enum` is handy:

```
enum Direction {
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right
}
```

Then use that in your code, possibly with a `switch`:

```
switch (direction) {
    case Direction.Up:
        // ...
        break;
    case Direction.Down:
        // ...
        break;
    case Direction.Left:
        // ...
        break;
    case Direction.Right:
        // ...
        break;
}
```

[More about enums.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: I'm very beginner and I didn't realised that I'll have to use enum. Thanks, that's what I was looking for :).

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have suggested, use an enum:

```
class Scroll {
    public static enum Direction { up, down};
    public static void scroll( Direction direction) {
        if ( direction == Direction.up) {
            System.out.println("UP");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("DOWN");
        }
    }
}

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scroll.scroll( Scroll.Direction.up);
    }
}
```

You can see it working in [this demo](http://ideone.com/ZU3OY).

Comment: I'm very beginner and I didn't realised that I'll have to use enum. Thanks, that's what I was looking for :).

Answer (score 0):

if (up) then up was pressed

if (down) then down was pressed.

boolean data types are (true/false, 1/0) so if you call

```
if (down)
```

then it will enter if down is "true".